# Webscraping a Website with a Js category script

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I would like some help scraping a website with this js category script. The script apparently makes it challenging to scrape the site since it limits the output i get

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580001' == '00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580003') {
            $('.ragingCarousel').hide();
            $('.lipBannerDiv').show();
        }  
        var parentLocation = window.location.href;
        if (parentLocation.toLowerCase() === "/event/inplay" || parentLocation.toLowerCase() === "/event/livesport/" || (parentLocation.toLowerCase() === "/bet/eventmultimarket" && $('#multi-head').hasClass('inPlayBg'))) {
            $('#sb_id.active, #mb_id.active, .betslip-trapezoid, #placeCashBet, #removeAllOutcomesBtn, #betslipBtn, #BetslipBtn, #placeFreeBet, #removeAllOutcomesBtn').addClass("liveInPlayClr");
        }      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: whats the website you are trying to scrape ? Let us know (if u are allowed to disclose that info). Also what is that weird if loop with such a long hexadecimal string; shed light on that please.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. The site is a betting website. and that is the script for the Js used. With overnight research i found selenium a good pull for JavaScript rendered websites. I will send a sample code for future young scriptwriters.